# Identify channels in a wav file?

Tags: python, audio, wav

I have numerous audio wav files.

Every audio files have 2 channels and each channel contains voices of 2 different persons so I want to get the channel where the activity is more or we can say the channel where the speaker is saying more and I have to delete the other channel.

As of now I am doing this with audacity but can i do it via python or any terminal command in ubuntu?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you using SQL for this, better go through the API, altering the DB yourself could cause trouble. What's the problem with multiple POST requests?

Comment: I dont want to loop over the post request, Is their any other way around?

Comment: Any way by which a single POST request can make the job done.

Comment: Don't think so if it's not in the API docs

Comment: OK Boss , I think I should roll over with multiple post request, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Idea is to separate both the channels and then get the size of both, cause in wav files size is directly proportional to activity in that channel.